# Is clipping done automatically in Three.js?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, webgl, three.js, clipping

So, I was reading about clipping in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28computer_graphics%29) Wikipedia article. It seems pretty essential to any and all games, so, do I have to do it, or is it done automatically by Three.js, or even WebGL? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass values for the near and far clipping planes to your camera object:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far );
```

near and far can contain values for example `near = 0.1` and `far = 10000` so an object which lies between these values will be rendered.

EDIT:

near and far, represent the clipping planes for your world. In a scene with thousands of objects and textures being drawn at once, it would be taxing on the CPU and GPU to try and show everything. Even worse, it would be wasteful to draw the things you cant even see. The near clipping plane is usually relatively close to the user, whereas the far clipping plane is somewhere off in the distance. As objects cross the far plane, they spontaneously appear or disappear. Some games use fog to make the appearance and disappearance of objects more realistic.

Comment: But what do they represent? A distance? In what axis? Please elaborate a bit moar.

Comment: Added description I found on http://sites.google.com/site/vadimtutorials/assignments/7creatinggameswithwebglandthreejs

Comment: Most important reason to set the near and far planes as close to each other as possible is to have some depthbuffer resolution. A high depthbuffer resolution is good to prevent "Z-fighting" (co-planar faces flickering).